# vim assign value to list by index

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

How can I reassign the value of a list in vim?

```
g:my_list = [1,2,3,4]
function! My_func(num)
   set g:my_list[num] = 20
endfunction

:call My_func(2)
E518: Unknown option: g:my_list[num] =
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `let` for variables, `set` is for options.

Additionally you need to prefix function arguments with `a:`

```
let g:my_list = [1,2,3,4]
function! My_func(num)
   let g:my_list[a:num] = 20
endfunction

:call My_func(2)
```

See:

- :help let in vim help
- **Vimscript variable scoping** in http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-vim-script-1/index.html.